# Visual Basic Get Json Value

Tags: json, vb.net

I am making an application and I need to read a certain value from a json file.

The json file is formatted as follows...

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "id": [
        6856,
        3667
      ],
      "uid": 15749645081288,
      "file_id": 6856,
      "name": "Name",
      "version": "001",
      "category_id": 4,
      "category_name": "OLD_VERSION",
      "is_primary": false,
      "size": 4,
      "file_name": "Name_001-1539-001-1633022640.zip",
      "uploaded_timestamp": 1633022640,
      "uploaded_time": "2021-09-30T17:24:00.000+00:00",
      "mod_version": "001",
      "external_virus_scan_url": "https://www.virustotal.com",
      "description": "Version 001 Public",
      "size_kb": 4,
      "size_in_bytes": 3961,
      "changelog_html": "Public",
      "content_preview_link": "URL"
    },
    {
      "id": [
        6872,
        3667
      ],
      "uid": 15749645081304,
      "file_id": 6872,
      "name": "Name_002",
      "version": "002",
      "category_id": 1,
      "category_name": "MAIN",
      "is_primary": true,
      "size": 4,
      "file_name": "Name_002-1539-002-1633106391.zip",
      "uploaded_timestamp": 1633106391,
      "uploaded_time": "2021-10-01T16:39:51.000+00:00",
      "mod_version": "002",
      "external_virus_scan_url": "https://www.virustotal.com/",
      "description": "Update 002 . See changelog.",
      "size_kb": 4,
      "size_in_bytes": 4150,
      "changelog_html": "Stuff",
      "content_preview_link": "URL"
    }
  ],
  "file_updates": [
    {
      "old_file_id": 6856,
      "new_file_id": 6872,
      "old_file_name": "Name_001-1539-001-1633022640.zip",
      "new_file_name": "Name_002-1539-002-1633106391.zip",
      "uploaded_timestamp": 1633106392,
      "uploaded_time": "2021-10-01T16:39:52.000+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I am in need of the "file_id" Value

The Code I have is as follows

```
    Dim json As String = ModLinkData(n)
    Dim read = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json)
    Dim FileID As String = read.Item("files").ToString
```

This will properly give me everything Under "files". I can not figure out how to ger the file_id value. When I change "files" to

Comment: `files` is an [array of items](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm)so you need to pick one item and then access its `file_id` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use strong typing for this, so I would look into JSON Serialization

You can create a class in .NET by copying your json string to the clipboard, then

> In Visual Studio put the cursor where you want the new classes
>
>  Edit >> Paste Special >> Paste JSON as Classes

And the result is this (I have changed some array types to Lists in Rootobject)

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property files As List(Of File)
    Public Property file_updates As List(Of File_Updates)
End Class
Public Class File
    Public Property id As Integer()
    Public Property uid As Long
    Public Property file_id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property version As String
    Public Property category_id As Integer
    Public Property category_name As String
    Public Property is_primary As Boolean
    Public Property size As Integer
    Public Property file_name As String
    Public Property uploaded_timestamp As Integer
    Public Property uploaded_time As Date
    Public Property mod_version As String
    Public Property external_virus_scan_url As String
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property size_kb As Integer
    Public Property size_in_bytes As Integer
    Public Property changelog_html As String
    Public Property content_preview_link As String
End Class
Public Class File_Updates
    Public Property old_file_id As Integer
    Public Property new_file_id As Integer
    Public Property old_file_name As String
    Public Property new_file_name As String
    Public Property uploaded_timestamp As Integer
    Public Property uploaded_time As Date
End Class
```

Since you are already referencing NewtonSoft.Json, we can use the deserialization method therein

```
Dim json = ModLinkData(n)

Dim rootobject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(json)

Dim fileIDs = rootobject.files.First().id ' this is an array
Dim fileID1 = fileIDs(0)
Dim fileID2 = fileIDs(1)

Console.WriteLine(fileID1)
Console.WriteLine(fileID2)
```

Output

> 6856
>
> 3667

This is superior to your method if you know the design of the data at design-time, because you get strong typing. Compare

```
Dim FileID = read.Item("files")
```

to

```
Dim fileIDs = rootobject.files.First().id
```

and see that in my example `files` is a concrete property of the object, while in yours `files` is a variable string you use to index a property which returns a `JToken`

Anyways I think you mainly had an issue with expecting a single value when an array was returned, which would be an issue in either case but with serialization you are notified by the compiler instead of at run-time.